# str.upper().isupper() might be False

Tags: python

I saw this statement in the official [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) :

```
str.upper().isupper() might be False
```

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: Followup question: might `str.upper().islower()` be `True`?

Comment: @Hammerite:yes, for example `ß` (DF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the string is number or is made of characters without an uppercase variant (special characters etc.)
For example:

```
>>> '42'.upper().isupper()
False
>>> '-'.upper().isupper()
False
```

And as expected:

```
>>> '42a'.upper().isupper()
True
```

Be carefule, since there is some strange behaviour for many unicode characters (see the answer from thg435: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495101/531222)

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. Many characters that do have uppercase variants will still return false.

Comment: Thanks I added that! Why is the follow up wrong? Is there a string for which `.upper().islower()` is `True`? `'ß'.upper().islower()` is `False` in my python versions… (2.7.1, 2.6.5)

Comment: Well, your edit is wrong again - you should have used `u"ö"` and `isupper` would work just fine with that. See my answer and the link therein for correct examples.

Answer (score 4):

More context to their statement:

> str.upper().isupper() might be False if s contains uncased characters
>   or if the Unicode category of the resulting character(s) is not “Lu”
>   (Letter, uppercase), but e.g. “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).

An example of an uncased character:

```
>>> '1'.upper().isupper()
False
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, `isupper`/`islower` functions are broken in python. First, they use an incorrect definition of "cased". There are lots of symbols in Unicode that have upper/lower case variants, but don't belong to the `L` category. For example, `Ⓐ` is clearly uppercase, and does have the lower case equivalent `ⓐ`, but `"Ⓐ".isupper()` is False in python. See [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/msg144802) for more details.

Second, there's a logical mistake. `isupper` is the same as "all cased chars are upper in this string" and if there are no cased chars, it should return True, not False, just like built-in `all()` does ("all unicorns are red" is true). This way the confusion in question could be easily avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If string consists of unicode characters that doesn't support uppercase:

```
>>> "عربية للفوتوشوب".upper().isupper()
False
```

`str.upper` makes no sense for numbers:

```
>>> "3432".upper().isupper()
False
```

Answer (score 1):

There are things that have no upper case (I guess only letters do, and not even in all languages).

So those won't get uppered by `upper` and then not be `isupper`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its true in case the string contains digits and other characters that have no upperCase